# Dart how to get max duplicated element in a list

Tags: dart

I have `List list= [1,2,3,4,4,4,9,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8];`

how can i return 8 as max repeated value

Comment: Are the elements always adjacent , or can the `8`s be spread out all along the list? What if there is no max repeated value? List of equally many of each value? Including the empty list?

Comment: thanks Im, elements not always adjacent.. if there is no max return first element,

Comment: What is max repeated value? 1) Max value from all repeated values? 2) Max value from values with max times repeated? Hard to understand.

Comment: What is max repeated value of this data?  [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 9, 6, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7]; 4, 7 or 8?

Comment: If the values are same return any one of them

Comment: If the values are same return any one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void main() {
  final list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 9, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8];
  print(findMaxDuplicatedElementInList(list)); // 8
}

T findMaxDuplicatedElementInList<T>(Iterable<T> list) => list
    .fold<Map<T, int>>(
        {},
        (map, element) =>
            map..update(element, (value) => value + 1, ifAbsent: () => 1))
    .entries
    .reduce((e1, e2) => e1.value > e2.value ? e1 : e2)
    .key;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just write it out, as straight-forward as possible:

Assuming the equal elements are always adjacent, and list cannot be empty, return arbitrary element with maximal count if there is more than one:

```dart
T maxDuplicated<T>(List<T> elements) {
  var element = elements.count;
  var count = 1;
  var maxElement = element;
  var maxCount = count;
  for (var i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var nextElement = elements[i];
    if (element != nextElement) {
      element = nextElement;
      count = 1;
    } else {
      count += 1;
      if (count > maxCount) {
        maxElement = element; 
        maxCount = count;
      }
    }
  }
  return maxElement;
}
```

Assuming elements come in random order, so we need to remember every element we have seen,
still not allowing an empty list as input:

```dart
T maxDuplicated<T>(List<T> elements) {
  var maxCount = 1;
  var maxElement = elements.first
  var seen = <T, int>{maxElement: maxCount};
  for (var i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var count = seen[element] = (seen[element] ?? 0) + 1;
    if (count > maxCount) {
      maxCount = count;
      maxElement = element;
    }
  }
  return maxElement;
}
```

(Alternatively, I'd sort the list first, if allowed, to always be in the former situation. It's not *faster* than using a map, if we assume hash map lookup to be a constant time operation, but it will be more memory efficient.)